# How to insert a new row into a table related to a row in another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to insert a row into a table while having the FK field reference the PK field in the related table, but it does not compile. this is what i have so far.

```
Insert into Location(LocNo, FacNo, LocName) 
values('L120', 'F111','Door');
```

The FacNo needs to relate to the PK facNo in the Facility table, so i have made the FacNo here the same, but when i try and run this it does not compile. What am i doing wrong?

> 1. Insert a new row into the Facility table with facility name “Swimming Pool”.
> 2. Insert a new row in the Location table related to the Facility row in modification problem 1. The new row should have “Door” for the
>      location name.

I have already done question one, but i am having trouble with the second question.

Comment: Is this Oracle or SQL-Server? use only the appropriat tags please!

Comment: Also, show what error you are seeing.

Comment: this is oracle and there is no error showing. When i run it it just continues to load, so the system never stops running, but it also never shows any data or error message. Eventually i have to stop it because it is not doing anything. @JorgeCampos

Comment: Then we need some more context or code. Because just with this it won't be possible to answer your. I could give you some guessing, like: Have you added your code into a transaction? Are you commiting after it finishes? Is there any rollback on your code?

Comment: that is all the code i have. here is the question, the tables have already been created, so i am just trying to follow the instructions. I already did question 1. i am very new to this, sorry for the rudimentary question.                                                                                                 1. Insert a new row into the Facility table with facility name “Swimming Pool”.
2. Insert a new row in the Location table related to the Facility row in modification problem 1. The new row should have “Door” for the location name. @JorgeCampos

Comment: Can you add into your question the create tables statement ? and what is the client program you are running this command

Comment: Show us the insert you used for the `facility` table and also show us the **exact** error message you get when inserting into the `location` table.